# What produces a commit message like: Merge branch 'master' of ... into 'master'

Tags: git

How is this kind of commit message produced?

```
Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/AAA/BBB into 'master'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message was most probably produced by merging in a pull request on Github